# Do you know how to solve geovornoi naive geometries problem?

Tags: python, geopandas, voronoi

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from geovoronoi.plotting import subplot_for_map, plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area
from geovoronoi import voronoi_regions_from_coords, points_to_coords
gdf = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/heejb/Desktop/R&E/gwangju/point.shp")
gdf.head()

boundary = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/heejb/Desktop/R&E/gwangju/gj.shp")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 10))
boundary.plot(ax=ax, color="gray")
gdf.plot(ax=ax, markersize=3.5, color="black")
ax.axis("off")
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()

boundary = boundary.to_crs(epsg=3857)
gdf_proj = gdf.to_crs(boundary.crs)

boundary_shape = cascaded_union(boundary.geometry)
coords = points_to_coords(gdf_proj.geometry)

poly_shapes, pts, poly_to_pt_assignments = voronoi_regions_from_coords(coords, boundary_shape)

fig, ax = subplot_for_map()
plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area(ax, boundary_shape, poly_shapes, pts, poly_to_pt_assignments)
ax.set_title('Voronoi regions of Schools in Uppsala')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,12))
plot_voronoi_polys_with_points_in_area(ax, boundary_shape, poly_shapes, pts, poly_to_pt_assignments,
voronoi_and_points_cmap="tab20c",
points_markersize=20)
ax.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I tried to make voronoi diagram on map, but every time I try I got this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/heejb/Desktop/rne.py", line 20, in <module>
    gdf_proj = gdf.to_crs(boundary.crs)
  File "C:\Users\heejb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 816, in to_crs
    geom = df.geometry.to_crs(crs=crs, epsg=epsg)
  File "C:\Users\heejb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 527, in to_crs
    "Cannot transform naive geometries.  "
ValueError: Cannot transform naive geometries.  Please set a crs on the object first.
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Your shapefile does not have assigned CRS (projection) to it. You have to do it manually before using `to_crs`. Unfortunately, you have to know which one should it be.

```py
boundary = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/heejb/Desktop/R&E/gwangju/gj.shp")
boundary.crs = <add CRS here>
```